# facebook insights paqe view using facebook api's

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

```
    209652442394600/insights?metrics/page_views?monthly
```

i want to get the number of views on monthly bases but my query is giving response like that

```
             {
        "data": [
               ], 
         "paging": {
           "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/209652442394600/insights?   debug=all&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1428469526&until=1428728726", 
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/209652442394600/insights?debug=all&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1428987926&until=1429247126" }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

donot follow the comments but use it for evaluating on any other date base

```
             function p_view()
               {
                //data:Array[10],
                FB.api("/144765045682596/insights/page_views?   period=day&since=1427846400&until=1429142400", function (response) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                    {
                        var thread = response.data[i].values;
                        var s=13;
                        //if (thread.values[13] == thread.values[i])
                        //{
                        var tm = thread[s].end_time;
                        var th = thread[s].value;
                        document.getElementById('datev').innerHTML = tm;
                        document.getElementById('viewers').innerHTML = th;
                        //    var values = thread.values;
                        //    //var comment = thread.
                        //}
                    }
                });
                    }
```

this work perfect